# How to flag term reference without flagging term?

Tags: users, flags, taxonomy-terms

I need do something like the skills system in linkedin.

The logged user with role "employee" have a profile2 called "employee". In this profile I need add a term reference field where the user can add his skills or create some skills new by Autocomplete term widget (tagging)... Like in linkedin.

After that, the other authenticated users can confirm the single skill of a user.

I tried to do this with taxonomy, term reference field (in the profile2 "employee") and flag... The problem is that if a user add the skills by term reference field, eg. term1, term2, and an other user confirms (flags) that skills, the terms are flagged for all users. So if an other user add term1 and term5 the current user visits his page and the term 1 is alredy flagged.

Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) This is a Q+A site for specific questions about Drupal, I'm afraid we can't advise you how to build a site/feature from scratch. Please see the [help] for more details.

Comment: Thanks Clive, I dont want you help me to build a website from scratch. This is only a feature of my website and I am looking for a suggestion about how can implement it. Its enough that you give me some suggestions or trik about...

Comment: Sorry, I must have read that completely wrong first time round I didn't take in the last paragraph. I don't know the answer I'm afraid but this is re-opened now so hopefully someone will...

Comment: Thanks Clive :) I do something with field collection. In this way i can flag every record (field collection item) singolary... But I think is not a good solution...

Comment: Hello. I also missed the important part, it seems. Before @Clive did it. Sorry it happened, glad it's figured out now. It might help if you would make your question's title less general. What you really ask has way less to do with LinkedIn than with term flagging. Title like "How to flag term reference without flagging term?" would help 1) avoid misreads and 2) attract attention of people who may actually know how to do that.

Comment: Thanks Molot you're right! 
I hope someone give me some idea on how to do... Meanwhile, I'm thinking about the possibility to use a field "entity reference" (referenced to the terms) and a field (hidden to the user) of type "field collection". So I can allow the user to add all the skills in only one field (throught tags widget) and then, by a loop in Rules, to create the respective items of the collection so as to flag them individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [Relation module](https://drupal.org/project/relation).

Relation allows you the create relations between entities that *are* entitties too. So the scheme will be:

- Create a relation between your users and the skills entities (they can still be taxonomy terms).
- Because these relation instances between your users and the skills are entities you can create a flag for this relation entities. So, when a user adds a skill to the profile you will have to create one relation entity with the user (or profile2*) and the skill.
- When anotheruser wants to aprove this user's skill she will flag that entity relation. No other user is affected.

I checked Relation time ago and I remember that creating relations was a little bit tricky. I don't remember how to make relations so I can't help you in this point, sorry. You may need some custom code to achieve what you want.

*: to decide between Profile 2 or user take into account how are you going to show this information. For example, think which options fits better with Views.